# Title and Subtitle-Text side by side HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm training to do a Report in this simple code. I want to put the Title Report and the subtitle side by side. How do I make this adjustment?

This is my html code:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* background: linear-gradient(to top left, red 10%, white 70.5%); */
  background: whitesmoke;
}

div#header.title-page {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 220px;
}

h1.title {
  font-size: 50pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page">
    <div id="header" class="title-page">
        <h1 class="title">Quarterly Report</h1>
        <h1 class="subtitle"><span>Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text Huge text </span></h1>
        <h2 class="author">Me</h2>
        <h2 class="date">2019-10-18</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I'd like to put the date at the top right and my name at the bottom right.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CSS flex` to get the items aligned side by side. Now for the date and name, you can just align the text right using `text-align: right;`

```css
html {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.date,
.author {
  text-align: right;
}

h1.title {
  font-size: 50pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page">
  <div id="header" class="title-page">
    <h2 class="date">2019-10-18</h2>
    <div class="title_wrapper">
      <h1 class="title">Quarterly Report</h1>
      <h1 class="subtitle">Sub Title</h1>
    </div>
    <h2 class="author">Me</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I noticed that you changed the code putting putting the author outside the div. There is a way to use the `flex css`without doing this??

Comment: you mean you want everything inside `#header` ?

Comment: so, you mean everything needs to go inside ` <div id="header" class="title-page">` ??

Comment: can the title and subtitle go inside a second div which is inside `<div id="header" class="title-page">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201125/discussion-between-nidhin-joseph-and-laura).